# How to use a contract after it has been deployed in migrations

Tags: web3js, truffle, javascript

I'm trying to us a contract in a truffle project.
This is part of a migration.js file.

```
deployer.deploy(token,companyID).then(function(){
    var starttime = web3.eth.getBlock(web3.eth.blockNumber).timestamp + 300000000;
    var endtime = starttime + 1000000;
    GG = token;
    return deployer.deploy(tokenICO, token.address, tokenwallet, rate, goal, tokenwallet, starttime, endtime).then(function()
    {

        console.log("token object: " + token);
        GG.approve(tokenICO.address,16000000);
    });
});
```

In this case I want to use the approve function of the token contract but
I get the following error:

```
TypeError: GG.approve is not a function
at (location)
at <anonymous>
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:160:7)
```

Is there an alternative way of going about this?

Comment: Is GamerGold a contract? Is it deployed?

Comment: GamerGold was a typo it should be correct now.

Answer (score 1):

You could do in this way.

```
 var GG;
 deployer.deploy(token,companyID).then(function(){
  var starttime = web3.eth.getBlock(web3.eth.blockNumber).timestamp + 300000000;
  var endtime = starttime + 1000000;
return deployer.deploy(tokenICO, token.address, tokenwallet, rate, goal, tokenwallet, starttime, endtime).then(function()
{
    token.deployed().then((inst)=> {
    GG = inst;
    console.log("token object: " + token);
    GG.approve(tokenICO.address,16000000);
  });

});
});
```

Comment: Another valid alternative was in a deleted answer: `token.at(token.address).approve(tokenICO.address,16000000);`